# Scanner is no longer reading lines - throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

My Scanner was working fine, reading lines in just dandy and now it is no longer working and continues to throw `NoSuchElementException: No Line Found` error.

My code:

```
        try {
            File file = new File("Word200D16.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++){
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    elementsToAdd[i] = line;
                }
            }

        } catch(Exception er) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + er);
        }
```

Is there anything **obviously** wrong with this code that I am overlooking? I want each line to be saved into my string array `elementsToAdd`.

Comment: You're misusing the pattern. `hasNextLine` checks for one line. You then attempt to read 200 `nextLine`s`. 1 for sure vs 200 not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything obviously wrong with this code that I am overlooking?

Yes. You are checking `hasNextLine` once then calling `nextLine` 200 times in a loop without checking.